# Appropriate merge of different dataframes

Tags: r

If I have different dataframes with the same columns names what kind of bind/merge should I implement.

Example df1:

```
stock,price
stockA, 2
stockB, 10
```

Example of df2:

```
stock, price
stockC, 3
```

Example of df3:

```
stock,price
stockJ, 33
```

Merged

```
 stock,price
    stockA, 2
    stockB, 10
    stockC, 3
    stockJ, 33
```

Comment: You need `rbind` not `merge`. `rbind(df1, df2, df3)`.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend `bind_rows` from `dplyr` -- it will handle aligning columns in case there are slight differences. It also handles lists, which may make it easier to handle cases created by `lapply` or `split`

Example:

```
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)
```

You can also easily track which data.frame they came from using the `.id` argument:

```
bind_rows(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3, .id = "whichDF")
```